# What do you call livestreaming in text?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

When a website posts latest developments of something using text, pictures, and videos as the events unfold in real-time ([example](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/feb/21/ukraine-crisis-president-claims-deal-with-opposition-after-77-killed-in-kiev)), what do you call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term is mentioned in the first sentence of the summary on the page you linked. It is ***liveblog***.

Comment: So it could be used as a verb too, couldn't it?

Comment: @Sergey yes it could.